# How to get the PC name of a user

Tags: php, computer-vision, ip

I  want my user to login only with his computer.
In the user creation page I have a field for the user's PC name, for example "AHMAD-PC" must be inserted so that he can only login to the system with that computer.
How can I get the pc name of my users?

Answer (score 0):

A direct and short answer would be **you can't**.

Simply because `PHP` runs on the server, not the client machine. Hence `PHP` doesn't have access to the client computer name.

As you can see below, here's what a `HTTP` request-header contains as information:

```
request-header = Accept 
            | Accept-Charset           
            | Accept-Encoding          
            | Accept-Language          
            | Authorization            
            | Expect                   
            | From                     
            | Host                     
            | If-Match                 
            | If-Modified-Since        
            | If-None-Match            
            | If-Range                 
            | If-Unmodified-Since      
            | Max-Forwards             
            | Proxy-Authorization      
            | Range                    
            | Referer                  
            | TE                       
            | User-Agent
```

None of those information actually contains the computer name.

You might be better off by using client IP address, but you would still get few problems with that in case your client has a dynamic IP.